# Graphing Apple Health data for more than one year

Tags: software-recommendation, health.app

I just migrated from Fitbit to Apple Watch and transferred my data. The one disappointment is that while Apple Health keeps all data, its graphs show at most the past year, but it's often useful to see longer trends. Fitbit showed 5 y or all-data (as long as possible). Until Apple Health offers longer graphs (e.g. on my iPhone), is there some other app that can conveniently offer such graphing options for Apple Health data?

Comment: In what format can you export the data? Then put it in Numbers or similar.